# Cleaning list to remove semi-duplicate values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of of video links. Some of these links are *almost duplicates*, meaning they contain almost the same link except that it has `x_480.mp4` instead of `x.mp4`. **Not** all links have those "_480" at the end.

How can I clean the list to get only the ones that end with `_480.mp4`, removing their alternate versions, and keep the ones without a `_480.mp4` version?

Example:

```
videos=["VfeHB0sga.mp4","G9uKZiNm.mp4","VfeHB0sga_480.mp4","kvlX4Fa4.mp4"]
```

Expected result:

```
["G9uKZiNm.mp4","VfeHB0sga_480.mp4","kvlX4Fa4.mp4"]`
```

**Note**: all links ends with `.mp4`. Also, there are no `_480.mp4` without original one.

By the way `len(videos)` is 243.

Comment: Do you care about order of the resulting list?

Comment: @OndrejK. No the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go the `dict` route to not have to check for existence of items in a list (would become a (performance) problem for large lists). For instance:

```
list({v[:-8] if v.endswith("_480.mp4") else v[:-4]: v
      for v in sorted(videos)}.values())
```

That is compact way to say.

Construct me a dictionary whose key is incoming `v` without last 8 characters for values ending with `"_480.mp4"` or otherwise just stripped of last four character and being assigned value of the full incoming string.

Give me just values of that dictionary and since input was a `list`, I've passed it to a list constructor to get the same type as output.

Or broken down for easier reading, it could look something like this:

```
videos=["x.mp4","y.mp4","z.mp4","x_480.mp4"]

video_d = {}

for video_name in sorted(videos):
    if video_name.endswith("_480.mp4"):
        video_d[video_name[:-8]] = video_name
    else:
        video_d[video_name[:-4]] = video_name

new_videos = list(video_d.values())
```

It uses a virtual base name (stripping `_480.mp4` or `.mp4`) as dictionary key. Since you do not care about resulting list order, we've made sure `_480` suffixed entries are `sorted` after the "plain" entries. That way if they appear, they overwrite keys created for values without `_480` suffix.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two lines of code:

```
to_remove = {fn[:-8] + '.mp4' for fn in videos if fn.endswith('_480.mp4')}
cleaned = [fn for fn in videos if fn not in to_remove]
```

The first line uses a set comprehension to extract all of the `_480.mp4`
filenames, converting them to their unwanted short versions. They are
stored in a `set` for quick searching.

The second line uses a list comprehension to filter out the unwanted
filenames.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It loops through the videos until it finds one which ends with `"_480.mp4"`. It then splits the title and get the starting bit and add `".mp4"` to to create the video title which you want to remove. It then loops through the videos again and removes the video with that title.

```
videos=["x.mp4","y.mp4","z.mp4","x_480.mp4"]

#Loops through all the videos
for video in videos:
    if "_480.mp4" in video:
        #Removes the "_480" part of the video title
        start = video.replace("_480", "")
        for video2 in videos:
            if video2 == start:
                videos.remove(start)

print(videos)
```

Comment: Not sure why because it works with the example you gave.

Comment: it does work on this example but not on actual list , this example is too simple the names are much longer than just `x.mp4`

Comment: @AmjasdMasdhash Try replacing the line `start =  video.split("_")[0] + ".mp4"` with `start =  video[:-8] + ".mp4"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do this with one liner list comprehension.

```
[x for x in videos if x.split('.')[0] + '_480.mp4' not in videos]
```

Comment: That does a linear search through `videos` for every item; it’s O(N^2).